# Probability of matching numbers in random sets

Tags: probability

Hi I am working on a game that involves a set of numbers.  For example lets use the number set of $1$ through $4$.  Suppose I take $1,2,3,4$ and randomize the order and then write them down on a piece of paper directly on top of another set of a random order of set of $1$ through $4$.  How do i figure out the probability of getting $0$ matches, $1$ match, $2$ matches and $4$ matches.  I believe $3$ matches would be impossible since you have $1$ number left so it would default to a match of $4$.

example:

$2 , 1,  3 ,4$
$1,  2,  3, 4$

In this random example above I have $2$ matches.  The $3$ and the $4$ match.  Is there a mathematical formula that I can use to do the math quickly especially for larger sets of numbers for all possible combinations.

Thank you.

Comment: for some reason it didn't show the line break the example is suppose to be:

Comment: you can still edit your post if you want

Comment: There are only 24 possibilities for four numbers. Write them all out (and the same for 3 numbers), calculate the probabilities directly, and see if you notice any patterns or ideas that might help you answer your question. Post what you find and you might get more help.

Answer (score 0):

4 numbers:

1 2 3 4

1 2 4 3

1 3 2 4

1 3 4 2

1 4 2 3

1 4 3 2

2 1 3 4

2 1 4 3

2 3 1 4

2 3 4 1

2 4 1 3

2 4 3 1

3 1 2 4

3 1 4 2

3 2 4 1

3 2 1 4

3 4 1 2

3 4 2 1

4 1 2 3

4 1 3 2

4 2 1 3

4 2 3 1

4 3 1 2

4 3 2 1

I noticed a random set matches 4 numbers 1 time, 2 numbers 6 times, 1 number 8 times and 9 times there are 0 matches.

3 numbers:

1 2 3

1 3 2

3 2 1

2 1 3

2 3 1

3 1 2

I noticed a random set matches 3 numbers 1 time, 1 numbers 3 times, and 2 times there are 0 matches.

As you can see this is very manual and tedious and I figured there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d(j)$ denote the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement,that%20has%20no%20fixed%20points.) of a set of $j$ elements. Let $f(n,k)$ the number of permutations of $n$ elements that fix $k$ elements. This can be calculated by taking the product of the number of ways to choose the $k$ elements that we fix and of the derangements of the remaining $n-k$ elements. Thus,

$$f(n,k)={n \choose k}d(n-k)=\frac{n!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}{k!}. $$

Dividing out by $n!$ will give you the probability you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand any of this.  Can you show me the actual math for a set of 4 numbers.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Can you pinpoint what steps of my reasoning you do not understand? For the "actual maths", I am not exactly sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?